# Cardinality of the countably infinite product of a two-point set $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm so confused about cardinalities of some sets. What is the countable infinite product of a two points set $\{0,1\}$? Does it have the same cardinality as the real number $\mathbb R$? Or is the infinite product just countable?

Could anyone give me the answer?

Comment: think of the binary representation of the numbers in $[0,1]$

Comment: I want to know why you think it might be countable.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a set and consider the set $\{0,1\}^X$ of all maps $X\to\{0,1\}$. Then there is a bijection
$$
f\colon \mathcal{P}(X)\to\{0,1\}^X
$$
($\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$) defined by sending each subset $A$ of $X$  to its characteristic function
$$
\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\in A$}\\
0 & \text{if $x\notin A$}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $\{0,1\}^X$ has the same cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

The countably infinite product of the set $\{0,1\}$ is simply the set of all infinite binary strings which Cantor showed to be uncountable in the classic [diagonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#An_uncountable_set) argument.